# Finding angle measurements

Tags: geometry

Angles $\angle AOB$ and $\angle COD$ are supplementary. $OE$ is a bisector of $\angle AOC$ and $OF$ is a bisector of $\angle BOD$. Find the measure of $\angle EOF$.

Geometry was never my strong point in mathematics. I am having trouble visualizing what it is I am trying to solve. I know $\angle AOB + \angle COD=180$. After that it gets weird because it says $OE$ bisects $\angle AOC$, but $\angle AOC$ is just a straight line in my picture. Please post a sketch of this drawing so I can see what I am looking for.

Comment: hint : supplementary angles need not be linear pair angles

Comment: They are a linear pair of angles because they have a common middle point $O$. There is no way to draw this other than as a linear pair. Tranverse angles don't work

Comment: I'll show you pic in few minutes, meantime keep thinking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below picture :

[image]

$\angle AOB + \angle COD = 180^\circ  \implies  2x+z + z + 2y = 180^\circ $

Can you solve $\angle EOF$ ?